# Gmail categories in Evolution

Tags: evolution, gmail

How do I capture Gmail categories using Evolution?

I'm looking for something to let me see Uncategorized, Soc.net., Notifications, Discussions, and other in different folders; or somehow else divide it.

Comment: Not supported via IMAP. Unless someone has written a plugin to support these gmail features, I think you are out of luck. I stick to using labels alone as they map to IMAP folders nicely.